# Make image jump to random spots on screen, and loop x10? HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

This is what i have so far, it makes my red circle appear and then when clicked it moves from the top left of the screen to the coodinates x, y(300, 800)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body
{
background-color:#000080;
}
h1
{
</style>

<title>Mouse click game</title>
<h1 style="text-align:center;color:white;font-family:verdana;font-size:50px;">Left click on the dots!</h1>

</br>
</br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function red_circleClick()
{
var red_circle = document.getElementById('red_circle');
red_circle.hidden = true;



red_circle.style.top = 300 + "px";
red_circle.style.left = 800 + "px";

red_circle.hidden = false;

}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<img src="/Users/lorraine/Desktop/MOUSE/red_circle.png" id="red_circle" onclick="red_circleClick();" style="position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100; width: 200; height: 200;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**What i need it to do is move to a random spot on the screen and do that 10 times.**

So I need it to appear, user clicks on it. When they click it jumps to another spot onscreen. when they click it again in its new location it jumps to an new spot onscreen, and repeat a certain amount of times(10)

**Is it possible that the circle could appear in a location outside the current screen? Like x,y(1000, 1000)**

Found this code, just not 100% on how/where to insert it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImg()
{
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);


var obj = document.getElementById("emotion");

obj.style.top = x + "px";
obj.style.left = y + "px";


 obj.onclick= "changeImg();"
 }
```

New enough to Javascript and html!

Thanks very much for the help in advance!

Comment: This suspiciously looks like a homework.

Comment: Are you going to implement it somewhere?  Excitingly where?

Comment: I suggest you learning html and Js somewhere instead of getting solution written by someone else

Comment: And no you cannot go outside the browser window...

Answer (score 0):

This function gets run whenever you click the dot

```
function red_circleClick()
{
var red_circle = document.getElementById('red_circle');
red_circle.hidden = true;


red_circle.style.top = 300 + "px";
red_circle.style.left = 800 + "px";

red_circle.hidden = false;

}
```

All you have to do is randomize your numbers

```
red_circle.style.top = 300 + "px";
red_circle.style.left = 800 + "px";
```

Open up a console in chrome or what have you and run `Math.random()` Then try `Math.floor(.1433)` Then maybe `Math.floor(.019231*100)` See what you can get. Replace 300 and 800 with whatever you come up with.

[image]

As for making it stop at 10 times, just use an if statement and a counter.